# Coolant 2004 Honda Civic

Tags: honda, civic, coolant

Can I put coolant in the same place that I put water in my car or does it have to go in the coolant reservoir?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Instead of using water, use the blue pre-mix especially made for Honda engines. The D17A engine in your vehicle *does not* like regular antifreeze (can cause the head gasket to leak after a long bit of exposure) and straight water will dilute what is in there already, making it weaker (less boil over protection) as well as cause corrosion and deposits in the cooling system.

Answer (score 1):

You can put coolant in the radiator. If that is where your putting water, then yes that is fine. Make sure you check your coolants directions, you may need to dilute it first. Long as the reservoir moves the overflowed coolant back into the system then you can add it here as well.